# facebook comment plugin: remove like button

Tags: facebook

The FB: comment plugin comes with both a like button and comment box.  Does anyone out there know how to remove the like button from the facebook comment plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working:

> To remove (hide) the like-button that
>   comes above the comments-box To hide
>   the Like botton, you will need to add
>   2 attributes and create a CSS file.
>   1. simple="1"
>   2. css="http://yoursitedomainname.com/fb_comments.css"
>
> ```
> <fb:comments expr:title='data:post.title'
> ```
>
> expr:url='data:post.url'
>   expr:xid='data:post.id' simple='1'
>   css='http://yoursitedomainname.com/fb_comments.css'/>
>
> in the css file add this style code:
>
> ```
> div.like, div.like div {display:none;}
> ```
>
> If you want you can just link to my
>   hide CSS file:
>   http://www.fileden.com/files/2006/10/3/258652/hidelike.css

Thanks to Gil Goldshlager, original post @ forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=58903

Answer (score 0):

I've also searched for this answer but found nothing. I guess it's not possible for the moment. But if someone knows anything about this, I would also like to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mctaco/Gil Goldshlager did not work for me. i assume, they only work with the old comments plugin. But i tried around with the tags and this one was working for me, to remove the like button:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"></div>
```

This code comes from django. if you are using another server side language, then you have to replace `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}` with the absolute uri from the page, where you want to have the comments plugin installed.

If you omit the data-href attribute, the like button is displayed.